# Sum of Binary Numbers

Tags: c

I was brushing up Data Structures using C and C++ from Tenenbaum, first chapter says a question in exercise to sum binary numbers.

My logic:

1. Convert binary to decimal
2. Take sum
3. Convert decimal sum to binary

But, problem arises when I pass argument by putting method name directly instead of passing variable which could store the values.

In debugging, I tried to print the value of the sum in decimal and in binary. it gave correct results, when I moved one at a time.

This is surely a compile time error and my logic seems correct.

Hoping to receive some help, as I need to solve this using C language.

Compiler I'm using is gcc on Mac.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

long bin2deci(long);
long deci2bin(long);
long add(long, long);

int main(void)
{
    long binnum, binnum2;
    printf("Enter a number in binary\n");
    scanf("%ld", &binnum);
    printf("Enter another number in binary\n");
    scanf("%ld", &binnum2);
    printf("Sum is %ld \n", deci2bin(add(bin2deci(binnum), bin2deci(binnum2))));
    return 0;
}

long bin2deci(long a)
{
    long digit, decimal, i=0;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        digit = a%10;
        a=a/10;
        decimal += digit*pow(2, i);
        i++;    
    }
    return decimal;
}

long deci2bin(long a)
{
    long i = 1, binary =0, rem;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        rem = a%2;
        a = a/2;
        binary = binary+ (rem*i);
        i = i*10;   
    }
    return binary;
}

long add(long a, long b)
{
    long sum;
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: To help with debugging, I suggest you split up the expression `deci2bin(add(bin2deci(binnum), bin2deci(binnum2)))` into smaller parts. For example `long temp1 = bin2deci(binnum);`, and then use `temp1` when calling `add` (why use a separate function for this?), storing the result in another temporary variable which is then passed to `deci2bin`. With that change, print all the temporary values. And edit your question to include the input, the actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: You do know that `power()` returns a `double`.

Comment: Assuming a compiler error is usually foolish speculation.

Comment: Computers only have binary numbers - everything else is presentation to the user. So what exactly is your input? Something like "01010101" ? It is probably much faster to read that as a string, then check each character and sum up values each time you find a 1. All the division and floating point calculations in your program are slow.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `decimal` Make it `decimal = 0`

Comment: What do you think decimal 10000000 converted to binary your way would be? Will your `long` data type handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is, because you forgot to initialize `decimal`.

After you do that you get the correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

long bin2deci(long);
long deci2bin(long);
long add(long, long);

int main(void)
{
    long binnum, binnum2;
    printf("Enter a number in binary\n");
    scanf("%ld", &binnum);
    printf("Enter another number in binary\n");
    scanf("%ld", &binnum2);
    printf("Sum is %ld \n", deci2bin(add(bin2deci(binnum), bin2deci(binnum2))));
    return 0;
}

long bin2deci(long a)
{
    long digit, decimal = 0;
    double i=0;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        digit = a%10;
        a=a/10;
        decimal += digit * (long int )pow( 2, i);
        i++;
    }
    return decimal;
}

long deci2bin(long a)
{
    long i = 1, binary =0, rem;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        rem = a%2;
        a = a/2;
        binary = binary+ (rem*i);
        i = i*10;
    }
    return binary;
}

long add(long a, long b)
{
    long sum;
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}
```

You probably noticed that I declared `i` as a `double` and I made a cast when you called `pow`  here:

```
decimal += digit * (long int )pow( 2, i);
```

Output:

```
==4134== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4134== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4134== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4134== Command: ./program
==4134== 
Enter a number in binary
0110
Enter another number in binary
1001
Sum is 1111 
==4134== 
==4134== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4134==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4134==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 2,048 bytes allocated
==4134== 
==4134== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4134== 
==4134== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4134== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Every time a student calls `pow(2,i)` in a loop, a beautiful butterfly dies because of global warming.

Comment: I think `long` is 8 bytes on gcc, same as `long int`. Also gcc initializes stack variables to zero (I am not sure about gcc on Mac) But you are right, initialization should be done manually and not left to the compiler.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani [This happens](https://pastebin.com/raw/aE87RDSn) when you do not initialize that variable.

Comment: I don't know what I am talking about then. gcc does not initialize stack variables to zero.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani From what I know, only Global and Static variables if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Skip pow() function it cause loss of precision when used with integers since it is made to work with double. Your code looks good and will work if your replace pow() with a loop doing the same job.